# Oracle varchar string replacement

Tags: string, oracle

I have a table (x) in a database and column(y) of data type varchar. This column includes values like 1. , 2\, .5, 2], 4.3 etc.

I am trying to replace all the values in column which have special characters except the ones that have a value after dot.

eg: I don't want to replace values like 2.3, 4.5, 7.1.

If there is no value after dot or a value starting with dot I would like to replace dot with null.

eg:

- 1., 2. should be replaced as 1, 2.
- .1, .2 should be replaced as 1, 2 as well.

I tried below script but it didn't work

```
update <table_name> 
set <column_name> = regexp_replace(regexp_replace(column_name, '[^A-Z0-9 ]', '.'),
                                              ' {2,}', ' ')
/
```

Please help.

I am using Oracle 11g DB.

Comment: I don't understand... the string you show, `1. , 2\, .5, 2], 4.3`, is a SINGLE input string (in a single row)? And the result must be a comma-separated list of numbers, either integers or decimals? Then: I understand why you want to replace `23.` with `23`. But why do you want to replace `.2` with `2`, and not with `0.2`? Are you aware that `.2` is a common variant of `0.2` in many countries? Please confirm that you **really** want to replace `.2` with `2` as you said, and you won't come back to change the problem statement.

Comment: So - other than the decimal point, you want to simply remove all the special characters between commas? Can there ever be LETTERS in the string, and if so, how do you need to handle them? Then - what if you have something like `....,32.9.2, ....` in the input string? (TWO decimal points?) How about sign, `2. , 30$, +12.5,-42.23`? How do those need to be handled?

Comment: @mathguy The string is not SINGLE input string. Each string I mentioned is  new value in a row. The reason why I am trying to replace .2 with 2 not with 0.2 is the actual value is 2. During data migration for some values dot is getting added before the number. Yes I want to remove all special characters. There are no letters in the string. I don't have any TWO decimal point strings. +, -, $ signs should also be replaced with null value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way. First we use a regular expression function to remove all characters OTHER THAN digits and period. Then we apply TRIM to the result, to trim (remove) the period only if it is the first or the last character.

The WITH clause is not part of the query; it is there only to create the test data for myself. Just use the query (from SELECT...) with your actual table and column names.

```
with
  inputs ( str ) as (
    select '2.'   from dual union all
    select '-4.2' from dual union all
    select '3?*'  from dual union all
    select '32.'  from dual union all
    select '.3'   from dual union all
    select '5$8'  from dual
  )
select str, trim( '.' from regexp_replace(str, '[^0-9.]') ) as new_str
from   inputs
;

STR  NEW_STR
---- -------
2.   2   
-4.2 4.2 
3?*  3   
32.  32  
.3   3   
5$8  58
```